# Elasticsearch bulk operation failing for large dataset

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I want to insert my database details into Elasticsearch db. The problem is that my table contains a large number of records (15537) and I am not able to insert and it appears to be very slow. The code I used is given below. 
I am using the bulk API of Elasticsearch.

```
bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing()
for b in City.objects.using('qoe').all().iterator()))
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: res = [i for i in parallel_bulk(
                chunk_size=10000,client=es,max_chunk_bytes=300 * 1024 * 1024,thread_count=4, actions=(b.indexing() for b in City.objects.using('qoe').all().iterator())
            )]          Everything is work while creating new indexes in elasticsearch using parallelbulk,but the process appears to be very slow.Any method to speed up the indexing process

Comment: Here is the ES guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/bulk.html